# Unable to reproduce minimal working example Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I downloaded and installed the Rcpp package recently in order to speed up the code of my own package using some C++ code.

The first thing I do is making a package with `Rcpp.package.skeleton(name="firstpackage")`:

```
> Rcpp.package.skeleton(name="firstpackage")
Creating directories ...
Creating DESCRIPTION ...
Creating NAMESPACE ...
Creating Read-and-delete-me ...
Saving functions and data ...
Making help files ...
Done.
Further steps are described in './firstpackage/Read-and-delete-me'.

Adding Rcpp settings
 >> added Imports: Rcpp
 >> added LinkingTo: Rcpp
 >> added useDynLib directive to NAMESPACE
 >> added importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp) directive to NAMESPACE
 >> added example src file using Rcpp attributes
 >> compiled Rcpp attributes
 >> added Rd file for rcpp_hello_world
```

This generates a file system with folders `man`, `R` and `src` as it should. However the files `Makevars`, `Makevars.win` and `rcpp_hello_world.h` are missing in these folders, if I compare with the example on page 66-67 in the book *Seamless R and C++ Integration with Rcpp*. Why aren't these files generated like in the example? After installing `firstpackage` I cannot use the function `rcpp_hello_world()` so I guess it is because of the missing files.

**edit:** It is clear now that the problem is not the missing files but something else. I tried again, now exactly following the instructions:

```
> Rcpp.package.skeleton("ruben")
Creating directories ...
Creating DESCRIPTION ...
Creating NAMESPACE ...
Creating Read-and-delete-me ...
Saving functions and data ...
Making help files ...
Done.
Further steps are described in './ruben/Read-and-delete-me'.

Adding Rcpp settings
 >> added Imports: Rcpp
 >> added LinkingTo: Rcpp
 >> added useDynLib directive to NAMESPACE
 >> added importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp) directive to NAMESPACE
 >> added example src file using Rcpp attributes
 >> compiled Rcpp attributes
 >> added Rd file for rcpp_hello_world
```

Then I look at the files. (a bit weird but the file structure appears to be the same)

```
> system("tree ruben")
Folder PATH listing for volume OSDisk
Volume serial number is A811-3ED9
C:\USERS\N14083\DOCUMENTS\RUBEN
ÃÄÄÄman
ÃÄÄÄR
ÀÄÄÄsrc
```

Then I install the newly created package:

```
> system("R CMD INSTALL ruben")
* installing to library 'C:/Users/n14083/Documents/R/win-library/3.1'
* installing *source* package 'ruben' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="ruben.dll" OBJECTS="RcppExports.o rcpp_hello_world.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'ruben'
* removing 'C:/Users/n14083/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/ruben'
Warning message:
running command 'R CMD INSTALL ruben' had status 1
```

The installation fails:

```
library(ruben)
Error in library(ruben) : there is no package called ‘ruben’
```

**edit: solution** Download the Windows toolset (http://cran.at.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset) and set the PATH correctly, in my case:

```
pathRtools <- paste(c("c:\\Rtools\\bin",
                      "C:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\bin",
                      "c:\\PROGRA~2\\MIKTEX~1.9\\miktex\\bin",
                      "C:\\PROGRA~1\\R\\R-3.1.1\\bin\\i386",
                      "c:\\windows",
                      "c:\\windows\\system32"), collapse=";")
Sys.setenv(PATH=pathRtools)
setwd("C:/Users/n14083/Documents")
system("R CMD INSTALL ruben")
```

and then restart R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The book was current when it was written. As you now observe, the header is no longer included, neither are the `Makevars` *as they are no longer needed*.
2. That is because we now build with Rcpp Attributes. It is easier.
3. It still all works (of course).

Log below.

```
R> Rcpp.package.skeleton("ruben")
Creating directories ...
Creating DESCRIPTION ...
Creating NAMESPACE ...
Creating Read-and-delete-me ...
Saving functions and data ...
Making help files ...
Done.
Further steps are described in './ruben/Read-and-delete-me'.

Adding Rcpp settings
 >> added Imports: Rcpp
 >> added LinkingTo: Rcpp
 >> added useDynLib directive to NAMESPACE
 >> added importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp) directive to NAMESPACE
 >> added example src file using Rcpp attributes
 >> compiled Rcpp attributes
 >> added Rd file for rcpp_hello_world
R>
```

So let's look at the files:

```
R> system("tree ruben")
ruben
├── DESCRIPTION
├── man
│   ├── rcpp_hello_world.Rd
│   └── ruben-package.Rd
├── NAMESPACE
├── R
│   └── RcppExports.R
├── Read-and-delete-me
└── src
    ├── RcppExports.cpp
    └── rcpp_hello_world.cpp

3 directories, 8 files
R>
```

And use them:

```
R> system("R CMD INSTALL ruben")
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *source* package ‘ruben’ ...
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic  -c rcpp_hello_world.cpp -o rcpp_hello_world.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o ruben.so RcppExports.o rcpp_hello_world.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/ruben/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (ruben)
R>
```

And it *obviously* works:

```
R> library(ruben)
R> rcpp_hello_world()
[[1]]
[1] "foo" "bar"

[[2]]
[1] 0 1

R>
```

So please substantiate the claim

> After installing firstpackage I cannot use the function rcpp_hello_world() so I guess it is because of the missing files.

Running this skeleton is part of *every* unit test run so this has been tested literally thousands of time since the book was written.

Comment: I added an edit to illustrate the problem. It is like I am missing something in order to execute this code.

Comment: Still you / your system. Did you spot the line  `ERROR: compilation failed for package 'ruben'` ?  Something is not right on your machine.  The example package is _fixed_ and _builds everywhere_.  Go back to the basics, make sure you have a compiler installed etc pp

Comment: That was the problem indeed. I made an edit with the solution in the question post.

Comment: Good to know.  You probably want to set the `PATH` before R is started -- eg via yoru system settings or the files in the `etc/` directory below R.